# Integrate: the integral is probably divergent

Tags: r, math

I was doing some integration into a loop using integrate and I come up with an error I can't understand neither get rid of. Here is a MWE I could extract:

```
b=1/1.230219e-07
f=function(x)
{exp(-x/b)}
integrate(f,0, Inf)
```

this returns an error "Error in integrate(f, 0, Inf) : the integral is probably divergent" which is obviously false
`Error in integrate(f, 0, Inf) : the integral is probably divergent`

i tried to change the upper and lower and it work

```
b=1/1.230219e-07
f=function(x)
{exp(-x/b)}
integrate(f,0, 2)
```

and the reslut
`2 with absolute error < 2.2e-14`

i think the problem comes from the infinity, but i dont know how to solve it?

Comment: It's not C++. Don't spam tags

Comment: You're doing numerical integration, not mathematical integration, so theoretical niceties (the function is mathematically convergent) don't apply.  Numerical integration involves some strategy of calling the function to sample values (by calling `f()`), and adding up or averaging. The algorithm being used in `integrate()` [whatever it is] is presumably sensitive to the errors produced by each call of `f()` in your case.    Bear in mind there is no universal strategy that *always* bounds errors - your function is presumably one for which the strategy used in `integrate()` fails to bound errors.

Comment: so, whats should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Use package [`cubature`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=cubature), function `hcubature`.
By hand the integral is equal to `b` and that's the result `hcubature` finds.
Also, I have redefined the function to take `b` as a formal argument.

```r
library(cubature)

f <- function(x, b){exp(-x/b)}

b <- 1/1.230219e-07
b
#> [1] 8128634

eps <- .Machine$double.eps^0.5
hcubature(f, 0, Inf, b = b, tol = eps)
#> $integral
#> [1] 8128634
#> 
#> $error
#> [1] 0.05960908
#> 
#> $functionEvaluations
#> [1] 825
#> 
#> $returnCode
#> [1] 0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: why when I copy your syntax to R, its need so long time to run

Comment: @EDITHA It takes 0 secs on my system (R 4.2.2 on Windows 11).