# ERROR, The integral is probably divergent

Tags: python, r, math, integral

Haii guys, i have problem with code in R
i wanna running the integral code, but the code its doesnt work. is there anyone can help me?

```r
retensi = 1136074
b = 1/1.230219e-07  
sx = function(x)
{exp(-x/b)}
integrate(sx, retensi, Inf)
```

when i run this code, the ruslt is error `Error in integrate(sx, retensi, Inf) : the integral is probably divergent` i dont get it, where the mistake that i made can anyone help me? Please tell me detail of the correct code guys

the pov is how to solve this integral in R studio

[image]

Comment: How is this different from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74925507/integrate-the-integral-is-probably-divergent), posted 8 hours ago, and to which you have already received an excellent answer?

Comment: How is this question related to `python`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) Separate into two parts** Sum the integral from `retensi` to `a` plus the integral from `a` to Inf for an `a` that works.  We can find such as `a` by trying 10^i for i = 7, 8, ...  The code stops at the first `a` that works.

```
retensi <- 1136074
b <- 1/1.230219e-07  
sx <- function(x) exp(-x/b)
for(a in 10^(7:12)) {
  res <- integrate(sx, a, Inf, stop.on.error = FALSE)
  if (res$message == "OK") break
}

a
## [1] 1e+09

res
## 5.21431e-51 with absolute error < 9.7e-51
```

so at a value of a = 10^9 the integral from `a` to `Inf` is essentially zero so we can just calculate the integral from `retensi` to a = 10^9

```
res <- integrate(sx, retensi, a); res
## 7068377 with absolute error < 0.0044
```

**2) Symbolic integration** We can calculate the integral symbolically

```
library(Ryacas0)
x <- Sym("x")
b <- Sym("b")
Integrate(exp(-x/b), x)
## yacas_expression(-(exp(-x/b) * b))
```

and using that symbolic result

```
b <- 1/1.230219e-07  
retensi <- 1136074
(-exp(-Inf/b) * b) - (-exp(-retensi/b) * b)
## [1] 7068377
```

**3) Change of variables** Another method is to use a change of variables replacing x with a function that goes to infinity when the input to that function goes to some finite value.  Trying x = tan(y) we have dx = dy/cos(y)^2:

```
D(quote(tan(y)), "y")
## 1/cos(y)^2
```

The answer below checks with the above two.

```
b <- 1/1.230219e-07  
retensi <- 1136074
sx <- function(x) exp(-x/b)
sy <- function(y) sx(tan(y)) / cos(y)^2
integrate(sy, atan(retensi), pi/2)
## 7068377 with absolute error < 15
```

Comment: thankyouu fo the answer. I try with number 1 and 2, but the answer number 2 it doesn't work for me, because when I running the code, it take a long time, and I dot get the result. but answer number 1 its work for me

Comment: (2) works for me and gives the answer shown quickly.  Maybe you are trying it on a different function?  Yacas Integrate is somewhat limited in what it can integrate.  Suggest you also try (3).

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that the expression `exp(-x/b)` has such a small value at higher values of x that you are running into the limits of floating point arithmetic. For example:

```r
retensi = 1136074
b = 1/1.230219e-07 
sx <- function(x) exp(-x/b)

sx(1e9)
#> [1] 3.734803e-54
sx(1e10)
#> [1] 0
```

In fact, a quick manual binary search shows that numbers above 6,056,915,224 will return 0

```r
sx(6056915224)
#> [1] 4.940656e-324

sx(6056915225)
#> [1] 0
```

This means that you will get the best approximation of you integral if the upper limit of your integral is set to 6,056,915,224:

```r
integrate(sx, retensi, 6056915224) 
#> 7068377 with absolute error < 19
```

We can confirm this is right by simply finding the indefinite integral of your expression, which is: `-b e^(-x/b) + c` and noting that this is 0 when x is infinite, so the manual calculation is:

```
0 - (-b * exp(-retensi/b))
#> [1] 7068377
```

And if we are still unsure, we can confirm this in [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+e%5E%28-x%2F8128634%29+dx+between+1136074+and+Infinity)

Comment: how to do a quick manual binary search to get number 6,056,915,224